# How to make a "reference" to a struct in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, reference

In my program, I have a large (e.g. 100x100) array of structs, each struct having a fair amount of data (e.g. 1000 numbers, and some other fields). For example:

```
for x = 100 : -1 : 1
    for y = 100 : -1 : 1
        database(y,x).data = rand(30);
        database(y,x).name = sprintf('my %d %d', x, y);
    end
end
```

I would like to do a computation of 10-20 lines of code with my data; for example:

```
for x = 10 : 90
    for y = 10 : 90
        for dx = -9 : 9
            for dy = -9 : 9
                result = result + database(y + dy, x + dx).data(1, 1);
                result = result + 2 * database(y + dy, x + dx).data(1, 2) * database(y + dy, x + dx).data(2, 2);
                ... % more stuff here
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My code refers to current element of the database as `database(y + dy, x + dx)`. To make it shorter, I give a name to it (C++ would call it "reference"):

```
temp = database(y + dy, x + dx);
result = result + temp.data(1, 1);
result = result + 2 * temp.data(1, 2) * temp.data(2, 2);
```

This makes my code much shorter and clearer. However, this is also much slower, and profiling shows that the assignment `temp = ...` takes 70% of my execution time.

So my assumption is that Matlab **copies** the contents of the largish database element, eating my time. I think Matlab should be smart enough to do "copy-on-write", that is, copy the stuff only when it is changed later. However, this is not what happens in my case - my code only reads from the database, and doesn't change it.

So, how can I make an efficient read-only reference to a struct?

Comment: +1 good question - I would like to know the answer to this as well. Every approach I've tried (exploiting copy-on-write in function arguments, using global variables, using handle classes) has resulted in much slower code.

Comment: I thought using `libpointer` might help, but constructing and working with the pointer seems to be more expensive than I would have thought.

Comment: Arrays of structs are slow compared to structs of arrays. If your data allows it, try converting to struct of arrays and it will probably be a lot faster. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html#brh72ex-14

Comment: Matlab *does* do "copy-on-write" for other objects - like matricies. To test this you can generate a big matrix (~1gb in RAM), "copy" it, and then change a single element in the new matrix. You won't see the second copy in memory until you change that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is definately copying going on when you do:

```
temp = database(y + dy, x + dx)
```

This could be reduced perhaps by using:

```
temp = database(y + dy, x + dx).data
```

But obviously that would only work if you were just interested in the data in this part of the code.

That being said, I am not sure whether you can work around it without using inconvenient methods to structure your data. First of all you could benchmark your code after doing a replace all of `temp` by `database(y + dy, x + dx)` to assure that avoiding the copy will really help. If so you could try feeding `database(y + dy, x + dx)` to a subfunction, as typically variables in a subfunction are used with read acces if that is sufficient. However, I am not sure whether this also applies to parts of variables.

If none of the above helps, consider some of the oldest advice in the book:

For efficient calculations on big chunks of data, consider using matrices.